# javascript namespace call other function methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I try to change some way to call methods into namespace.

- Calling parent methods (I dont think its possible)
- Creating and call inheritance function
- Calling inside another method (mostly jquery onReady event function) (this.MyFunction() not working)

I split every namespace in files (want to keep it that way)

I try [How to call function A from function B within the same namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790982/how-to-call-function-a-from-function-b-within-the-same-namespace) but I didn't succed to split namespaces.

my fiddle sample got only 1 sub-namespace but could be more.

https://jsfiddle.net/forX/kv1w2rvc/

```
 /**************************************************************************
    // FILE Master.js
    ***************************************************************************/
    if (!Master) var Master = {}; 
    Master.Print= function(text){
        console.log("master.Print :" + text);
      $("body").append("<div>master.Print : " + text + "</div>");
    }

    /**************************************************************************
    // FILE Master.Test1.js
    ***************************************************************************/
    if (!Master) var Master = {};
    if (!Master.Test1) Master.Test1  = {};
    /**************************************************************************
    * Descrition :
    *   Function for managing event load/documentReady
    **************************************************************************/
    Master.Test1.onReady = function () {
        $(function () {
            Master.Test1.Function1();   //try to replace because need all namespace.          

            try {
                   this.Function2(); //not working
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log("this.Function2 not working");
                $("body").append("<div>this.Function2 not working</div>");
            }   

           try {
                this.Print("onReady");  //not working
           }
           catch(err) {
                console.log("this.Print not working");
              $("body").append("<div>this.Print not working</div>");
           }

          try {
                Print("onReady"); //not working
          }
          catch(err) {
                console.log("Print not working");
                $("body").append("<div>Print not working</div>");
          }     

        });
    }

    Master.Test1.Function1 = function () {
        console.log("Function1");
        $("body").append("<div>Function1</div>");    
        this.Function3();      //working because not inside another function   
    }

    Master.Test1.Function2 = function () {
            $("body").append("<div>Function2</div>");
        console.log("Function2");   

    }


    Master.Test1.Function3 = function () {
            $("body").append("<div>Function3</div>");
        console.log("Function3");

        Master.Print("Function3");  //try to replace because need all namespace.        
    }

    Master.Test1.onReady();
```

- I use Master.Test1.Function1(); and I want to change that because Function1 is inside the same namespace.
- I use Master.Print("Function3"); I dont think I can change that. the way I try to use it, it's more an inheritance function. but I dont know if theres a way to do that?

Maybe I should change the my namespace methode? maybe prototype will do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `this` in a variable because `this` inside `$(function() {})` will point to `document` object. The below will work provided you never change the calling context of `onReady` -- i.e. it is always called on the `Test1` object and not called on other context:

```
Master.Test1.onReady = function () {
    var self = this;
    $(function () {
        self.Function1();
        // ..
    });
}
```

To access `Print` you have to reference using the `Master` object like: `Master.Print()` as it won't be available in the `Test1` object

Answer (score 0):

`this` is `document` within `.ready()` or `jQuery()` alias for `.ready()` where `function(){}` is parameter `$(function() {})`. `this` at `this.Function2()` will reference `document`.

Answer (score 0):

"Objects" in javascript are not built the same way as in most object-oriented languages. Essentially, what you are building is a hierarchy of static methods that have no real internal state in-and-of themselves. Therefore, when one of the defined methods is invoked, the context (or state) of that method depends on what object invoked the method.

If you want to have any internal context, you will need to create an "instance" of an "object prototype". At that point, you can use "this.otherFunction" within your other functions. Here is a small example:

```
var MyObject = function() {};

MyObject.functionOne = function() {
    console.log("Function 1");
    this.functionTwo();
};

MyObject.functionTwo = function() {
    console.log("Function 2");
};

var instanceOne = new MyObject();
instanceOne.functionOne();
```

You might get some more information about object definition [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

Comment: most of the time, function are use as static (no need to create an instance). but its a way to do it. unfortunately, the problem for sub function is still there. the answer of saravana is more usefull for my problem.